# Is there a way to set a variable in a function without resetting the variable every time the function runs?

Tags: python

So what I mean by this is if you have this code for example:

```
def test():
  money = 0
  x = input('')

  if x == "givemoney":
    money = money + 100
    print(money)
    test()
  else:
    print("something")

test()
```

It'll reset money to 0 every time the function goes which makes sense but how could I stop that?

Comment: There is no second time around in the second example.

Comment: Can you explain more what you expect/what you want the code to do?

Comment: Change `input('')` to `input(">")` at least to see that the code waits for input

Comment: In the second code snippet, you are assigning `x` to `input('')` and that's the last thing your function does before returning.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the value of `money` to be maintained through separate calls of `test()` and not to be reset to zero each time the function is called?

Comment: In the first snippet, you are calling `test()` again and will do so forever if you keep saying `"givemoney"` layering stack frames upon stack frames. This is a terrible way to repeat code in Python and eventually you'll hit a stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop. Here money is defined and initialized in a scope local to the function when the function is called; this is why it reset for every call to `test()`.

```
def test():
  money = 0
  x = input('')
  while x != 'stop':
    if x == "givemoney":
      money = money + 100
      print(money)
      x = input('')
    else:
      print("something")

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first version you can make `money` an optional parameter to the function. When you call it from the top-level you allow it to default. When you make the recursive call, you pass the current value in place of the default.

```
def test(money = 0):
  x = input('')

  if x == "givemoney":
    money = money + 100
    print(money)
    test(money)
  else:
    print("something")

test()
```